# Convert from decimal to Binary

Tags: c++

Want to convert decimal to binary but am getting some bugs. 
 I am now learning the conversion of decimal numbers or numbers with
 type double to binary and am having some difficulties.

```
#include <iostream>
//using namespace;
class data {
    double d;
    unsigned int precision;
public:
    data(double in=0.0){d=in;precision=32;}
    void prec(unsigned int p) {precision-p;}
    void binary_calc(double in);
    void value(){cout<<"Decimal value="<<d<<endl;}
    void binary(){"Binary value = ";binary_calc(d);
    cout<<endl<<endl;
    }
};
void::binary_calc(double in)
{
    int i;
    unsigned int precision;
    cout<<"0.";  //program works on this format of numbers only
    for(i=0;i<precision;i++)
    {
        int*=20;
        if(in>-1)
        {
            in-=1;
            cout<<"1";
        }
        else cout <<"0";
    };
}

int main()
{
    data x(0.7), y(0.1), z;
    x.prec(20);
    x.value();
    x.binary();
    y.prec(32);
    y.value();
    y.binary();
    z.value();
    z.binary();
}
```

Comment: Did you try to compile it? And what is your expected result?

Comment: What are you trying to print? The binary representation of a double, or the binary representation of a decimal number represented by the double?

Comment: is it getting compiled ? I am seeing this "precision-p" statement. Is it a editing error? and what is the expected and the actual output

Comment: There is no decimal to binary conversion here. Just floating-poiint to binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to address some of the following first for it to compile:

```
using namespace std;
```

`void::binary_calc(double in)` to `void data::binary_calc(double in)`

`int*=20;` What are you trying to do there?

Comment: He probably wants `in*=20`. Anyway, his code won't even compile. Another issue: `void::binary_calc(double in)`.

Comment: @jweyrich Agreed. With the above changes, the code should compile and run, but what results it will give is another matter.

Comment: This is the output of the code above.


    Decimal value = 0.7
    Binary value = 0.10110011001100110011


    Decimal value = 0.1
    Binary value = 0.00011001100110011001100110011001


    Decimal value = 0
    Binary value = 0.000000000000000000000000000000000